# How to get label data from JSON from file contents

Tags: php, json

```
$json = file_get_contents('module=API&method=Referrers.getReferrerType&format=json&period=day&date=yesterday&disableLink=1&idSite=3');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

json data:

```
[{"label":"Direct Entry","nb_uniq_visitors":526,"nb_visits":593,"nb_actions":768,"nb_users":0,"max_actions":32,"sum_visit_length":83153,"bounce_count":513,"nb_visits_converted":0,"segment":"referrerType==direct"},{"label":"Search Engines","nb_uniq_visitors":230,"nb_visits":235,"nb_actions":631,"nb_users":0,"max_actions":71,"sum_visit_length":52233,"bounce_count":150,"nb_visits_converted":0,"segment":"referrerType==search","idsubdatatable":2},{"label":"Websites","nb_uniq_visitors":7,"nb_visits":7,"nb_actions":20,"nb_users":0,"max_actions":5,"sum_visit_length":835,"bounce_count":1,"nb_visits_converted":0,"segment":"referrerType==website","idsubdatatable":3}]
```

I'm trying to display each label for the referrer type.

1. Direct Entry
2. Search Engines
3. Websites

`$data[0]->label;` doesn't work

`$data->label;` doesn't work

`$data->label[0];` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, as you're converting the json data to associative array (nested), by passing `true` into the 2nd argument of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method:

```
$json = "[{\"label\":\"Direct Entry\",\"nb_uniq_visitors\":526,\"nb_visits\":593,\"nb_actions\":768,\"nb_users\":0,\"max_actions\":32,\"sum_visit_length\":83153,\"bounce_count\":513,\"nb_visits_converted\":0,\"segment\":\"referrerType==direct\"},{\"label\":\"Search Engines\",\"nb_uniq_visitors\":230,\"nb_visits\":235,\"nb_actions\":631,\"nb_users\":0,\"max_actions\":71,\"sum_visit_length\":52233,\"bounce_count\":150,\"nb_visits_converted\":0,\"segment\":\"referrerType==search\",\"idsubdatatable\":2},{\"label\":\"Websites\",\"nb_uniq_visitors\":7,\"nb_visits\":7,\"nb_actions\":20,\"nb_users\":0,\"max_actions\":5,\"sum_visit_length\":835,\"bounce_count\":1,\"nb_visits_converted\":0,\"segment\":\"referrerType==website\",\"idsubdatatable\":3}]";

$data = json_decode($json, true);
print_f($data[0]['label']);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You passed `true` to the second parameter to `json_decode()`. That makes it return an associative array. Thus, you can simply use the data like this :

`$data[0]["label"]`